# permutations of String Array in recursion

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

```
String[] test = { "la", "li", "lo" };
language(3, test);

private String language(int n, String[] syllables) { // example of N = 3
    for (int i = 0; i < syllables.length; i++) {
        String w1 = syllables[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < syllables.length; j++) {
            String w2 = syllables[j];
            for (int x = 0; x < syllables.length; x++) {
                String w3 = syllables[x];
                System.out.println(w1 + w2 + w3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a recursive method that can create any form of the String array.
But I'm unable to achieve this

**Variables**

```
n = amount of syllables  
syllables = String Array of the base words
```

**Output**

```
lalala
lalali
lalalo
lalila
lalili
lalolo
lilala
lolala
lilili
lololo
......
```

Comment: You need to pick single character and then select other characters. Then call the same permutation() method on *other character* in the String. if size of string ==2 return the original as well as its reverse. concatenate all strings returned by negative calls. happy coding.

Comment: you are aware there will be ```n^n``` strings in the output (if all elements are unique)?

Comment: I think that strictly speaking, lalala is not a permutation of the 3 strings. A permutation needs to have all 3 strings in every string

Comment: @shlomi33 well that depends on the definition, some might call it a permutation with repetitions

Comment: Argh! Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this with recursion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the result you are expecting:

```
String[] test = { "la", "li", "lo" };
language(3, test, "");
```

---

```
private static void language(final int n, final String[] syllables, final String currentWord) { // example of N = 3
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(currentWord);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < syllables.length; i++) {
            language(n - 1, syllables, currentWord + syllables[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks really understandable.

Comment: this also will print out duplicates for instance for ```{"la","la"}```

Comment: for my purpose, it doesn't matter if the input contains a duplicate. Thanks for pointing out though

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk The question never said that this is something that should be avoided, but if you really want to, you can just replace the first call to `language()` by `language(3, (new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(test))).toArray(new String[0]), "");`

Comment: @FlorentBayle well I never said it's something really bad, just pointed it out as a potential problem/slowdown :-)

Answer (score 2):

You'd need something along these lines:

```
private void recursiveMethod(int numberOfSyllablesToAdd, String[] syllables, String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < syllables.length; i++) {
        String newWord = word + syllables[i];
        if (numberOfSyllablesToAdd >= 0) {
            recursiveMethod(numberOfSyllablesToAdd - 1, syllables, newWord);
       } else {
            System.out.println(newWord);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This is really ineffective for multiple reasons (like not using a StringBuilder or StringBuffer to create the words)

Comment: add that ```void``` there :-)

Comment: Another problem with your method: you have to pass `2` as the first parameter when first calling the method, instead of `3`.

Comment: also it will print duplicates if the input array is not unique

Comment: Thanks for the efford, like Florent said, you have to pass a 2 instead of 3 to get a 3-syllable word.